# Bivariate probability distribution problem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

*Problem*: Let $X$ be a random variable such that $X \sim N(0, 1)$. Let $W$ be a random variable independent of X such that $\Pr [W = 1] = \Pr [W = −1] = \frac12$. Define $Y = WX$

Show that $Y$ has the same distribution as $X$.

I don't really know where to begin with this problem. I have an idea in mind for bivariate transformations but I'm not sure that's even what I need to do. I think it's intuitively clear that $X$ and $Y$ have the same distributions but...I don't know how to show it?

My attempt is as follows:

$$Y = WX \implies P(Y)=P(WX)$$
since $\Pr [W = 1] = \Pr [W = −1] = \frac12 \implies$ $W$ is a discrete random variable.

\begin{align}
\implies & \Pr(Y \le y) = \Pr(W=w)\Pr(X \le x) \\[10pt]
& = \sum_w \Pr(W=w) \cdot \frac1{\sqrt {2 \pi}}e^{-x^2/2}
= 1\cdot\frac1{\sqrt {2 \pi}} e^{-x^2/2} = \frac1{\sqrt {2 \pi}} e^{-x^2/2}
\end{align}

If this is correct please let me know because I just kind of guessed this is what I was supposed to do. If not, any help would be great.

Comment: I cleaned up some somewhat messy typesetting, and I did a bit more than that: Where it said $\displaystyle\sum_W \Pr(W=w)$, since that didn't appear to make sense, I changed it to $\displaystyle\sum_w \Pr(W=w)$, which makes sense. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be treating $\dfrac 1 {\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-x^2/2}$ as the cumulative distribution function of the $N(0,1)$ distribution.  That is incorrect; it is actually the density function.

You can say
\begin{align}
\Pr(Y\le y) & = \Pr\Big( (W=1\ \&\ Y\le y) \text{ or } (W=-1\ \&\ Y\le y)\Big) \\[10pt]
& = \Pr(W=1\ \&\ Y\le y) + \Pr(W=-1\ \&\ Y\le y) \\[10pt]
& = \Pr(W=1\ \&\ X\le y) + \Pr(W=-1\ \&\ {-X}\le y) \\[10pt]
& = \Pr(W=1)\Pr(X\le y) + \Pr(W=-1)\Pr(-X\le y) \\[10pt]
& = \Pr(W=1)\Pr(X\le y) + \Pr(W=-1)\Pr(X\le y) & & \text{(by symmetry of the} \\
& & & \phantom{(}\text{$N(0,1)$ distribution)} \\
& = \frac 1 2 \Pr(X\le y) + \frac 1 2 \Pr(X\le y) \\[10pt]
& = \Pr(X\le y).
\end{align}
Since $\Pr(Y\le y) = \Pr(X\le y)$, the two random variables $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution.

(The aforementioned "symmetry" just means that $X$ and $-X$ both have the same distribution.)